# Windows 7 network netbios

Tags: smb, netbios

When I use the nbtstat -c command
I see all the network devices except a local area connection that plugs in with a physical cable.
I see all devices - WIFI / VMWARE except local area connection.
What can be the problem? maybe my physical network card not support in netbios?

Comment: Is the Ethernet connection connected, with valid settings for IP etc? Does it show on an ipconfig?

Comment: @StevenDavison indeed. he gets an ip address, can ping the all network. but the device not found on the nbtstat for some reason..